# How to build a controlled two-qubit gate?

Tags: cirq

I have a two-qubit gate with below unitary:

```
    def _unitary_(self):
        st = np.sin(self.theta)
        ct = np.cos(self.theta)
        ei = np.exp(1j*self.phi)
        emi = np.exp(-1j*self.phi)

        return np.array([
            [1.,        0,          0,  0],
            [0,         ct,     ei*st,  0],
            [0,         emi*st,   -ct,  0],
            [0,         0,          0,  1.]
        ]
        )
```

I want to build a three-qubit gate in which one qubit serves as the control qubit on the above two-qubit gate while the gate is applied on the other two qubits.

Here is an example of such gate: Say the gate is applied on q0, q1, and q2 where q0 is the control qubit. The above 4*4 unitary should be applied to q1 and q2 if and only if q0 is 0.

How would the unitary of such three-qubit gate look like? (I'm doing this in Cirq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyTwoQubitGate().on(q1, q2).controlled_by(c)`

or

`MyTwoQubitGate().controlled().on(c, q1, q2)`

Comment: Thanks. Two follow up questions:
1) What if I have more than one control qubit for my MyTwoQubitGate?
2) What if some of the control qubits check for 0 and some others check for 1?
I'm interested to know if Cirq has features to allow above two cases.

Comment: I think I found the answer:
https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.ControlledGate.html#cirq.ControlledGate